# Obtener IDs de combobox

Tags: mysql, python, pyqt5, combobox

Estoy intentando migrar un sistema en Delphi/MySQL; a Python/PyQT5/MySQL. Pero estoy "atorado" en algo que pudiera ser algo muy simple.
Tengo 4 combobox. En CB1 cargo una tabla de ESTADOS. En CB2, una tabla MUNICIPIOS. En CB3 una tabla de COLONIAS; y en CB4 una tabla CALLES.

En la tabla ESTADOS tengo (idestado,estado)
En la tabla MUNICIPIOS tengo (idmunicipio,idestado,municipio)
En la tabla COLONIAS tengo (idcolonia,idmunicipio,colonia)
En la tabla CALLES tengo (idcalle,idcolonia,calle)

El combobox municipio, depende de la id de estado. El CB colonia, depende de la id municipio. Y así sucesivamente.

Cuando cambio CB1 (estados), necesito que el CB2 me muestre únicamente los municipios de dicho estado.
Cuando cambio CB2 (municipios), necesito que el CB3 me muestre únicamente las colonias de dicho municipio.
Cuando cambio CB3 (colonias), necesito que CB4 muestre las únicamente las calles de dicha colonia.

No se cómo obtener el IDEstado ni el IDMunicipio, ni el IDColonia, ni el IDCalle del item que estoy seleccionando del CB. Necesito algo como el currentText. Pero para obtener la ID (que no se ve)
No necesito el curremIndex, puesto que este maneja una secuencia de números consecutivos. Suponiendo que X colonia tiene solo 10 calles, pero una de esas calles, su ID es = 500, el curremIndex no me funciona
Espero haber sido explisito. De antemano muchisimas gracias.

```
def CARGAR_COMBO_ESTADO(self):
        cursor = conexion.cursor()
        consulta = "SELECT * FROM CATESTADO ORDER BY ESTADO"                    
        cursor.execute(consulta)
        resultado = cursor.fetchall()
        for estado in resultado:
            self.estado_cb.addItem(estado[1],str(estado[0]))
            self.estado_cb.setItemData(estado[0],estado[1])
        self.CARGAR_COMBO_MUNICIPIO()

def CARGAR_COMBO_MUNICIPIO(self):
        cursor = conexion.cursor()
        consulta = "SELECT * FROM CATMUNICIPIO WHERE IDESTADO = %s ORDER BY MUNICIPIO"                    
        cursor.execute(consulta,"AQUÍ NECESITO EL ID DEL ESTADO SELECCIONADO")
        resultado = cursor.fetchall()
        for municipio in resultado:
            self.municipio_cb.addItem(municipio[2])
            self.municipio_cb.setItemData(municipio[0],municipio[2])
        self.CARGAR_COMBO_COLONIA()

def CARGAR_COMBO_COLONIA(self):
        cursor = conexion.cursor()
        consulta = "SELECT * FROM CATCOLONIA WHERE IDMUNICIPIO = %s ORDER BY COLONIA"                    
        cursor.execute(consulta,AQUÍ NECESITO EL ID DEL MUNICIPIO SELECCIONADO)
        resultado = cursor.fetchall()
        for colonia in resultado:
            self.colonia_cb.addItem(colonia[2])
            self.colonia_cb.setItemData(colonia[0],colonia[2])
        self.CARGAR_COMBO_CALLE()

def CARGAR_COMBO_CALLE(self):
        cursor = conexion.cursor()
        consulta = "SELECT * FROM CATCALLE WHERE IDCOLONIA = %s ORDER BY CALLE"                    
        cursor.execute(consulta,"AQUÍ NECESITO EL ID DE LA COLONIA SELECCIONADA")
        resultado = cursor.fetchall()
        for calle in resultado:
            self.calle_cb.addItem(calle[2])
            self.calle_cb.setItemData(calle[0],calle[2])
```

Comment: Tengo una pequeña duda: digamos que en un momento dado los comboboxes muestran la información correcta, para hacerlo sencillo digamos que el municipio corresponde al estado seleccionado pero luego se selecciona otro estado entonces ¿que deberia mostrarse como elemento seleccionado en el combobox que muestra los municipios? Lo señalo porque obviamente deseas que se muestren los municipios de ese estado pero ¿que municipio de esa estado debe ser seleccionado por defecto?

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se maneja mucha informacion es mejor usar un modelo y afortunadamente el QComboBox soporta los modelos. Ahora yendo al problema real, este caso se puede usar la informacion del modelo que en una columna tiene el id por lo que usando la fila (el currentIndex) y columna. Cada vez que se cambie el index de un QComboBox se debe  recargar el modelo:

```py
import sys

import mysql.connector

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


def create_or_fill_model_from_query(connection, query, parameters=None, model=None):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    if model is None:
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    else:
        model.clear()
    if parameters is None:
        parameters = []
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
    except Exception as e:
        print("error", e)
        return

    for i, rowdata in enumerate(cursor.fetchall()):
        if i >= model.rowCount():
            model.insertRow(model.rowCount())
        for j, data in enumerate(rowdata):
            if j >= model.columnCount():
                model.insertColumn(model.columnCount())
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
            item.setData(data, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
            model.setItem(i, j, item)

    return model


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost", user="yourusername", password="yourpassword"
        )
        self.estado_cb = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.municipio_cb = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.colonia_cb = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.calle_cb = QtWidgets.QComboBox()

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.estado_cb)
        lay.addWidget(self.municipio_cb)
        lay.addWidget(self.colonia_cb)
        lay.addWidget(self.calle_cb)

        estado_query = "SELECT * FROM 'https://stackoverflow.com/'"
        model = create_or_fill_model_from_query(self.connection, estado_query)
        self.estado_cb.setModel(model)
        self.estado_cb.setModelColumn(1)
        self.estado_cb.currentTextChanged.connect(self.handle_estado_changed)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.municipio_cb.setModel(model)
        self.municipio_cb.currentTextChanged.connect(self.handle_municipio_changed)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.colonia_cb.setModel(model)

        self.municipio_cb.currentTextChanged.connect(self.handle_colonia_changed)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.calle_cb.setModel(model)
        self.calle_cb.setModelColumn(1)

        self.handle_estado_changed()

    @property
    def connection(self):
        return self._connection

    def handle_estado_changed(self):
        id_estado = self.estado_cb.model().index(self.estado_cb.currentIndex(), 0)
        municipio_query = (
            "SELECT * FROM CATMUNICIPIO WHERE IDESTADO = %s ORDER BY MUNICIPIO"
        )
        create_or_fill_model_from_query(
            self.connection,
            municipio_query,
            parameters=[id_estado],
            model=self.municipio_cb.model(),
        )
        self.municipio_cb.setModelColumn(1)
        self.municipio_cb.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def handle_municipio_changed(self):
        id_municipio = self.municipio_cb.model().index(
            self.municipio_cb.currentIndex(), 0
        )
        colonia_query = (
            "SELECT * FROM CATCOLONIA WHERE IDMUNICIPIO = %s ORDER BY COLONIA"
        )
        create_or_fill_model_from_query(
            self.connection,
            colonia_query,
            parameters=[id_municipio],
            model=self.colonia_cb.model(),
        )
        self.colonia_cb.setModelColumn(1)
        self.colonia_cb.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def handle_colonia_changed(self):
        id_colonia = self.colonia_cb.model().index(self.colonia_cb.currentIndex(), 0)
        calle_query = "SELECT * FROM CATCOLONIA WHERE IDMUNICIPIO = %s ORDER BY COLONIA"
        create_or_fill_model_from_query(
            self.connection,
            calle_query,
            parameters=[id_colonia],
            model=self.calle_cb.model(),
        )
        self.calle_cb.setModelColumn(1)
        self.calle_cb.setCurrentIndex(0)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```